# Can I check for pending signals and execute them immediately

Tags: c, linux, signals

What I want to do is to only handle signals at some known points in my code. So at those points I will check for a pending signal and execute its handler immediately.

I know I can use `sigprocmask` to block a signal and later unblock it, but sill in that way, the signal will be delivered at any point in time after unblocking, which I don't want. I want to execute the signal handler precisely at a specific location in my code. In other words, I want to make signal handling synchronous.

Is there a possible way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch any pending blocked signal using the `sigwait` family of syscalls. It's not possible to wait for both signals and other types of events concurrently though, if you do not want to block in sigwait you can first check if there's pending signals using `sigpending`.

If you're using an event driven design for your application you'll typically have several fds in a run loop. For that situation you should instead use a signal handler which writes to a `pipe`. The signal will be delivered asynchronously but will then appear in your run loop as just another fd that needs processing.

Comment: Per, using sigpending seems a good idea. Will have a loot at it. Thanks.

Comment: Per, what do you mean by other types of events? What kind of events?

Comment: `sigpending` is not a non-blocking version of `sigwait`; `sigpending` doesn't clear a pending signal. To handle a signal synchronously without blocking you have to use both; `sigpending` to check whether there are pending signals and `sigwait` to clear one.

Comment: @MetallicPriest tried to clarify the post. Also changed sigpending to be correct.

Comment: Charles, so if a signal is there and I call sigwait (after ofcourse checking for it through sigpending), will the handler be executed or I will have to manually make the call to the handler. If I do it manually, how will I pass the context parameters etc..

Comment: Since kernel 2.6.22 / glibc 2.8, you *can* wait for both signals and other events simultaneously, using `signalfd()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can simply use `sigwait` to clear each of the pending signals and then call the your signal handler function directly.

At the points in your code where you want to handle and clear pending signals you can use `sigpending` to check if there are signals waiting and then repeatedly call `sigwait` to clear the pending signals, manually calling a signal handling function to perform the required action.

Comment: But that would be inefficient. I don't want to wait unnecessarily, Just look for signals and handle them if they are pending, otherwise go on with the execution.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: `sigwait` doesn't wait if there's a signal pending and I thought you said that you already check for pending signals. `sigwait` is the only way I know of to use signals synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Any pending signals will be delivered immediately when you unmask them.  Just unmask/remask at the point where you want to let them be delivered.  If you are using threads be aware that asynchronous signals (like those you get from `kill`) can go to any thread that has them unblocked.

Comment: Ben, I didn't precisely understood what you mean by unmask/remask. You mean block them and unblock them immediately? Would you be so kind to give a small snippet of code doing that.